# How to set Excel Color Theme for a Workbook using C# and EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I've been trying to change the Excel color configuration that is in

> Page Layout >> Colors

using EPPlus with no success. Does anyone know what is the attribute for that and how to reference the themes that Excel has?

Thanks!

Comment: Thats a tough one.  What happens with this is excel generates an entire theme file in the xlsx zip.  It would be a lot of work to reproduce in epplus which is why they probably havent done it.  I think your best bet would either be a VBA macro or doing a bunch of xml work on the epplus zip file in code.  VBA should be easy but it does have the security requirements.  XML would get around this but it would be a lot of work.  Sorry I can give you a better answer.